# Setting up checkbox for qunit testing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, qunit

I am starting to work with QUnit. I have existing logic that is conditional on a check box state.

```
function CheckEmailRequirementSatisfied() {
if (isEdit == "false") {
    if ($("#EmailId").val() != "" || $("#IsOtherEmail").is(":checked")) {
        $("#EmailRequirementSatisfied").val("1");
    } else {
        $("#EmailRequirementSatisfied").val("");
    }
}
}
```

I have the following module with setup and tests.

```
module("CheckEmailRequirementSatisfied", {
setup: function () {
    $("#qunit-fixture").append('<input id="EmailId" /> ');
    $("#qunit-fixture").append('<input id="EmailRequirementSatisfied" /> ');
    $("#qunit-fixture").append('<input type="checkbox" name="IsOtherEmail" /> ');
}
});

test("IsOtherEmail true", function () {
isEdit = "false";
$("#EmailId").val("");
$("#EmailRequirementSatisfied").val("test value");
/*
    document.getElementById('IsOtherEmail').checked=true;
    $("#IsOtherEmail").prop("checked", true);
    $("#IsOtherEmail").attr("checked", "checked");
    $("#IsOtherEmail").val(true);
*/
CheckEmailRequirementSatisfied();

ok($("#EmailRequirementSatisfied").val() == "1", "Requirements should be set to 1");
});
```

I have tried all of the options in the commented block of the test to setup my checkbox. but it keeps failing out saying that it's not checked.

Using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js and http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.10.0.js

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that line be:

```
 $("#qunit-fixture").append('<input type="checkbox" id="IsOtherEmail" /> ');
```

i.e., 'id' rather than 'name'?

Comment: That did it. I looked at it, what seems like 100 times, and didnt see that.

Thanks.